# Python OpenCV Invalid Literal Error

Tags: python, opencv

I have `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.DS'` error. I am looking for solutions for a day but I couldn't fix it. My directory is not empty. I am trying to train a facerecognizer using OpenCV. I am trying to get photos of faces from my `train` directory but I cannot.

My code :

```
images = []
labels = []
for file in os.listdir('train/'):
    image = cv2.imread('train/'+file, 0)
    images.append(image)
    labels.append(int(file.split('_')[0]))
```

Photos in train are named is 1_001.pmg, 1_002.pmg and so on. I am looking for your help for my silly problem. Thanks!

ps. this code is from the answer of @Fabian here [how to notify user if there are common faces detected between two directories with python and opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052818/how-to-notify-user-if-there-are-common-faces-detected-between-two-directories-wi)

Comment: What exactly is unclear from stack trace you have received? It sounds quite obvious to me, `.DS` is unconvertable to int. There is only one place in your code where you do conversion, last line of `for` loop. Note that filenames prepended with dots are classified as _hidden_ files in most `*nix` systems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need it as an integer because faceRecognition.train function needs it like that. So I have to convert it to integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with `os.listdir('train/')`, as it returns a list of all the files in given directory which may be hidden to you, and `'.DS_Store'` is also among those files, you need to check if the string in the returned end with `.png` before passing them to `cv::imread`.

```
images = []
labels = []
for file_name in os.listdir('train/'):
    if file_name.endswith(".png"):
        image = cv2.imread('train/'+file_name, 0)
        images.append(image)
        labels.append(int(file_name.split('_')[0]))
```