# attributeerror: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'createlbphfacerecognizer'

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0, opencv-contrib

So i'm doing a little personal project but i keep getting this error when I try to create the recognizer. i have opencv-contrib and everything. Does anyone know whats going on? code posted below

```
import cv2, os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath)

recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()
```

it gets caught on that last line. I've tried reinstalling all modules already. Not really sure what else to do. The weird thing is it works on my laptop but not my desktop. They both have the same modules, same python release and running the exact same code.

Comment: How did u compile your `opencv_contrib`?

Comment: mark Peter's answer as the correct one man

Answer (score 22):

Had the same problem. Use:

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

It worked for my program.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks, where did you find this info if you don't mind me asking? I couldn't find this anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

Under Windows 7, I was able to resolve the issue by simply uninstalling and re-installing opencv:

```
pip uninstall opencv-contrib-python
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

The recogniser is called by:

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Answer (score 7):

There are some missing modules for contributed libraries in the default `pip install opencv-python` so you need `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV has removed the `cv2.face` module from version 4.4.0 onwards. This module was used for face recognition and included algorithms such as Eigenfaces, Fisherfaces, and LBPH (Local Binary Patterns Histograms).

Instead of using the `cv2.face` module, OpenCV now recommends using the `face_recognition` library, which is a third-party library that provides a simple interface for face recognition tasks. This library uses dlib's implementation of face recognition algorithms, which is more accurate and faster than the algorithms included in the `cv2.face` module.

You can install the `face_recognition` library using pip, by running the following command in your terminal or command prompt

```
pip install face_recognition
import face_recognition
```

Answer (score 2):

try this it worked for me

```sh
pip install --force-reinstall opencv-contrib-python==4.1.2.30
```

Answer (score 2):

```
recognizer = cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/late-answers/26181920)

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your opencv by "python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python" 
ps: you have to delete the CV2 repository  from the Python rep and then run this command (in the CMD windows) if it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Path for face image database
path = 'dataset'
recognizer = cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem running opencv Version 3.4.1. Here is what I did.

SPECS:
Raspberry pi 3B, OS: Raspbian, Version: 9 (Stretch), Python 3, opencv Version 3.4.1

> Check opencv version in python
>
> `import cv2`
>
> `cv2.__version__`

1) `sudo pip install opencv-contrib-python`

*After this I could not import cv2 in python until I installed the following.

2) `sudo apt-get update`

3) `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev`

4) `sudo apt-get update`

5) `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-serial-dev libqtgui4 libqt4-test`

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue with two commands:

First:  `sudo pip3 uninstall opencv-contrib-python`

Second:  `sudo python3 -m pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.3.0.9`

This fixed my issues. Hope it helps somebody!
Also, if you are using python2, replace “pip3” with “pip” and “python3” with “python”

Answer (score 1):

- Uninstall this package (opencv-python) by command :-
- ***pip uninstall opencv-python***
- Install the library opencv-contrib python using command :-
- ***pip install opencv-contrib-python***
- then add or check :-
- ***recognizer = cv2.face_LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()***
- It will work fine
- *The problem was in opencv-python library  cv2.face is not present so it shows attribute missing problem, so install new lib by uninstalling previous one if installed..*

Answer (score 0):

You are using Opencv 3.x, in the new version few modules has been removed. You have two options:
1. Add opencv_contrib module to your existing opencv 3.x version. 
Here's the link https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib
2.you can use older versions of Opencv. Like opencv 2.4.x

Answer (score 0):

open cmd , then --> pip install opencv-contrib-python

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by installing:
`sudo pip install opencv-contrib-python`.

Then look for correct format.

> python2 is default

Basically the problem is that python3 and python2 have different format of code.

`recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`

This is the format of python2.

`recognizer = cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()`

This is the format of python3

Answer (score 0):

Even I had this problem when I ran the code using **Jupyter Notebook**.
If you are running it on **Jupyter Notebook** , then download it as **pyhton(.py)** file and try to run it in Anaconda Prompt or Command Prompt. This solved the problem for me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Installing **opencv-contrib-python** solved the issue.
I had installed only opencv-python, After Installing opencv-contrib-python, solved the issue.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3 use pip3 instead of pip: 
`pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`

Then you can simply do:
`recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`

Answer (score 0):

write

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade
```

if gives error then
write

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python --user
```

it will work fine for `cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()`

Answer (score 0):

There are some missing modules for contributed libraries in the default `pip install opencv-python-contrib` so you need `pip install opencv-contrib-python --upgrade`

This will download a 41.5MB file and install that in your python package folder , after that you can check by simply First "import cv2" then typing "print(dir(cv2.face))" that will return a list of attributes in cv2.face which will include "createlbphfacerecognizer"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It's not entirely clear what your answer adds to the already posted answers which cover most if not all what you've mentioned here already. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer For formatting code, it's also useful to post full functional code using syntax highlighted code blocks rather than plain text, see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing an same issue after installation of these below command in my command prompt.

```
> pip install opencv-contrib-python
> pip install opencv-contrib-python --user
```

Facing this below error in **jupyter notebook.**

> Training done ---------------
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4424/3540845204.py in 
> 40 labels = np.array(labels)
> 41
> ---> 42 face_recognizer = cv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
> 43
> 44 # Train the Recognizer on the features list and the labels list
>
> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'

After i am tried with **visual studio code** but make sure your running with this below confirmation commands in your command prompt or terminal.

I will suggest you to try in command prompt.

> ```
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1348]
> (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Admin>python
> Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> import cv2
> >>> print(cv2.__version__)
> 4.5.5
> >>> **recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()**
> >>> **print(recognizer)**
> **<face_LBPHFaceRecognizer 000001F890F3D8D0>**
> >>>
> ```

After successfully fixed this issue, i have got these below outputs.

> ```
>       on.exe' 'c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher'
>   '55275' '--' 'c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Opencv\Faces\face.py' 
>   >   Training done ---------------
>    
>       PS C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Opencv\Faces>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Opencv\Faces'; & 'C:\Program
>   Files\Python310\pyth0' '--'
>   'c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Opencv\Faces\face_recognization1.py' 
>   >   Label = Elton John with a confidence of 0.0
>   >   Label = Elton John with a confidence of 0.0
>
>    on.exe'
>      'c:\Users\Admin\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher'
>      '55339' '--'
>      'c:\Users\Admin\Downloads\Opencv\Faces\face_recognization1.py'
>   >   Label = nidhi agarwal with a confidence of 0.0
> ```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30903481)

Answer (score 0):

The Library can change how we access methods or the method names by time.
So, keep an eye for that.

Here's the latest one:
`recognizer = cv.face.LBPHFaceRecogniser.create()`

Answer (score 0):

`clf=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create() AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'face'`

I also got this error...
This is because your opencv module is out of date.

so please uninstall opencv:

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

and reinstall opencv using this command:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

and replace this line to:

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer.create()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Latest Update:(2023)**

Got same error after alot of research on this Find the exact solution

First of all install fresh `opencv-contrib-python` As it has cv2.face.

And if you already `opencv-python` installed too? they conflict.

Uninstall the `opencv-python` and pick `opencv-contrib-python` to get your error will get resolve.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

**NOTE: Make sure to remove `opencv-python` from your project before installing `opencv-contrib-python`**

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35287747)

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV has removed the cv2.face module from version 4.4.0 onwards. This module was used for face recognition and included algorithms such as Eigenfaces, Fisherfaces, and LBPH (Local Binary Patterns Histograms).

Instead of using the cv2.face module, OpenCV now recommends using the face_recognition library, which is a third-party library that provides a simple interface for face recognition tasks. This library uses dlib's implementation of face recognition algorithms, which is more accurate and faster than the algorithms included in the cv2.face module.

You can install the face_recognition library using pip, by running the following command in your terminal or command prompt

pip install face_recognition
import face_recognition