# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'faces' in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-recognition

After referring to some Stack Overflow answers I did `pip install opencv-contrib`, still I am getting those errors.

code for training:

```
face_recognizer=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

code for facial detection:

```
faces,faceID = fr.labels_for_training_data('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\python tests\\0')
face_recognizer=fr.train_classifier(faces,faceID)
face_recognizer.save('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\python tests\\trainingData.yml')
```

And Error is :

```
 File "C:/Users/vsneh/OneDrive/Desktop/python tests/Face_detect_Tester.py", line 15, in <module>
    face_recognizer=fr.train_classifier(faces,faceID)
  File "C:/Users/vsneh/OneDrive/Desktop/python tests\faceRecognition.py", line 47, in train_classifier
    face_recognizer=cv2.faces.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'faces'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [attributeerror: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'createlbphfacerecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655699/attributeerror-module-cv2-face-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try update OpenCV with

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Comment: It worked in my case. Do you know how are these modules: opencv-contrib-python and openCV different?

Comment: I believe `opencv-contrib-python` is the unofficial pre-built OpenCV package. It's not the official OpenCV package released by OpenCV.org. There is also `opencv-python` which contains just the main modules of the OpenCV library while `opencv-contrib-python` contains both the main modules along with the contrib modules. You don't want to install both, pick only one.