# AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribtue 'face'

Tags: raspberry-pi, face-recognition, opencv, python

I'm getting error on this line, while my **opencv-python version is 3.4.6.27** and **opencv-contrib-python is 4.1.1.26**.

Anyone know what's the problem?

```
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [attributeerror: module 'cv2.face' has no attribute 'createlbphfacerecognizer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655699/attributeerror-module-cv2-face-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it work after i install a lower version of opencv-contrib-python which is same as my opencv-python version.

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.4.6.27
```