# AttributeError in OpenCV face recognition code

Tags: python

Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'Face'
```

Code:

```py
faceCascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
clf=cv2.Face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
clf.read("clf.xml")
```

I already installed opencv I can't find this package in the site packages or cv2.

Answer (score 0):

It's [`face` not `Face`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45655699/attributeerror-module-cv2-face-has-no-attribute-createlbphfacerecognizer):

```py
cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
```